# CreateUser fails using mongocxx 3.1.1 C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver, createuser

Using the MongoDB server 3.4.4 on Windows 10, the following command works just fine:

```
db.createUser(  
{  
    user: "Billy",  
    pwd : "123456",  
    roles :   
    [  
        { role: "userAdmin", db : "biolomics_index" },  
        { role: "dbAdmin", db : "biolomics_index" },  
        { role: "readWrite", db : "biolomics_index" }  
    ]  
}
```

Running the same command with the mongocxx 3.1.1 C++ drivers fails:

```
db.run_command(document{} << "createUser" << open_document <<  
    "user" << "Billy" <<  
    "pwd" << "123456" <<  
    "roles" << open_array <<  
        open_document << "role" << "userAdmin" << "db" << "biolomics_index" << close_document <<  
        open_document << "role" << "dbAdmin" << "db" << "biolomics_index" << close_document <<  
        open_document << "role" << "readWrite" << "db" << "biolomics_index" << close_document << 
    close_array << close_document <<  
    finalize);
```

with the error:

> "createUser" had the wrong type. Expected string, found object:
>   generic server error.

I can't find the syntax to generate the correct document. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`createUser` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createUser/), the username should be placed as a value of `createUser` instead of `user` field. Change your code to:

```
db.run_command(document{} << 
    "createUser" << "Billy" <<  
    "pwd" << "123456" <<  
    "roles" << open_array <<  
        open_document << "role" << "userAdmin" << "db" << "biolomics_index" << close_document <<  
        open_document << "role" << "dbAdmin" << "db" << "biolomics_index" << close_document <<  
        open_document << "role" << "readWrite" << "db" << "biolomics_index" << close_document << 
    close_array <<  
finalize);
```

**NOTE:**
As mentioned by Saghm in the comment, the MongoDB shell helpers are not exactly the same as the "run command" equivalents in the drivers. You can use the shell's `db.runCommand` if you want to try out things with the same BSON that the driver requires in `database::run_command`.

1. Consults [Database Commands Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) for available commands and parameters from within the driver.
2. The [`mongo` Shell Methods Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) describes methods, commands and parameters for interacting with the MongoDB server through `mongo` shell.

Comment: To provide some context for this, the MongoDB shell helpers are not exactly the same as the "run command" equivalents in the drivers. You can use the shell's `db.runCommand` if you want to try out things with the same BSON that the driver requires in  `database::run_command`.

Comment: @Saghm, thank you. Your comment has been added to the answer.